# Why does a 3D scene need to be voxelized before it can be transformed into a navmesh?

Tags: path-finding, navmesh

Why do solutions such as Recast voxelize a 3D scene before transforming it back into polygons?

Would it not be possible to just determine intersections of meshes, check for slope angles and adjust triangulations in that way? I think agent height problems could also be solved by testing sweeps upwards against the other meshes.

Comment: Nothing ever *needs* to be voxelized or rasterized. But people do it anyway because it is *useful*. You've tried computing the intersections as you describe already, I presume, and had trouble with it, which is why you came here to ask for help. You know first-hand how hairy and error-prone it gets. Is that not enough reason to try to simplify the problem to a regular grid?

Answer (score 2):

DMGregory's point about voxelization's simplicity seems about right.
Another reason though, is performance. With these navmesh algorithims, you *need* a way to reduce the complexity of a scene.

Voxelization is a way of reducing the complexity of high poly meshes. Additionally it has the same effect as spatial partitioning whereby the number of potential neighbors of any feature (triangle/voxel) is reduced to a small, finite amount. You can imagine, depending on the mesh, that a long triangle could require intersection checks with a large portion of the scene, while that will never be the case with a voxel.

If you're interested in different approaches then Recast, [here's a video by Casey Muratori](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YE8MVNMzpbo&ab_channel=MollyRocketMollyRocket) in which he explains the (real-time) walking system he developed for the Witness. From what I remember, instead of voxels, he uses sort of poles to quantize the world (thereby simplifying it)

Comment: I've also seen voxelization used as a way to eliminate problems with non-watertight/non-manifold geometry, so I suspect that's in play here too.

Comment: yeah I think Casey talks about this exact issue in his video. I've made some procedural IK crawlies before which use raycasts > navmeshes and they basically run into this problem unless the level geometry is made with special care and attention.